# Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Got an error: `Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'SugarProductSchema': title, brand, price, coverImage`
I fetched data with `graphql-request` and passing it via props:

```js
 <ProductCard
              title={product.title}
              brand={product.brand}
              price={product.price}
              coverImage={product.coverImage.url}
            />
```

then In my component I pass them with `SugarProductSchema` types but there is the error that I mentioned above. :/
/src/components/product-card/index.tsx

```js
import {
  Box,
  Center,
  useColorModeValue,
  Heading,
  Text,
  Stack,
  Image,
  Icon,
  HStack,
  Tooltip,
  Flex,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { FiShoppingBag } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { SugarProductSchema } from '@/types/sugar-product-schema';


export const ProductCard = ({
  title,
  brand,
  price,
  coverImage,
}): SugarProductSchema => {
  return (
    <Center py={12}>
      <Box
        role={'group'}
        p={6}
        maxW={'330px'}
        w={'full'}
        bg={useColorModeValue('white', 'gray.800')}
        boxShadow={'2xl'}
        rounded={'lg'}
        pos={'relative'}
        zIndex={1}
      >
        <Box
          rounded={'lg'}
          mt={-12}
          pos={'relative'}
          height={'230px'}
          _after={{
            transition: 'all .3s ease',
            content: '""',
            w: 'full',
            h: 'full',
            pos: 'absolute',
            top: 5,
            left: 0,
            backgroundImage: `url(${coverImage})`,
            filter: 'blur(15px)',
            zIndex: -1,
          }}
          _groupHover={{
            _after: {
              filter: 'blur(20px)',
            },
          }}
        >
          <Image
            rounded={'lg'}
            height={230}
            width={282}
            objectFit={'cover'}
            src={coverImage}
          />
        </Box>
        <Stack pt={10} align={'center'}>
          <Text color={'gray.500'} fontSize={'sm'} textTransform={'uppercase'}>
            {brand}
          </Text>
          <Heading fontSize={'2xl'} fontFamily={'body'} fontWeight={500}>
            {title}
          </Heading>
          <HStack>
            <Text fontWeight={800} fontSize={'xl'}>
              {price}PLN
            </Text>
            {/* <Text textDecoration={'line-through'} color={'gray.600'}>
              $199
            </Text> */}
            <Tooltip
              label='Dodaj do koszyka'
              fontSize='md'
              bg='gray.50'
              hasArrow
            >
              <Flex as='span' textAlign='center'>
                <Icon as={FiShoppingBag} w={6} h={6} cursor='pointer' />
              </Flex>
            </Tooltip>
          </HStack>
        </Stack>
      </Box>
    </Center>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

my SugarProductSchema looks like:
/src/types/sugar-product-schema/index.ts

```js
export type SugarProductSchema = {
  title: string;
  brand: string;
  price: number;
  coverImage: string;
};
```

Comment: You used the SugarProductSchema as return type of the ProductCard component, not type of the props.

Comment: ok, should've been like this: `export const ProductCard = ({
  title,
  brand,
  price,
  coverImage,
}: SugarProductSchema) => {`